# Equality in the Cauchy Schwartz inequality?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

From Kreyszig's Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications:

> Prove that the dual space of $\Bbb R^n$ is $\Bbb R^n$
>
> Let $f(x) = \sum \xi_k \gamma_k$, where $\gamma_k = f(e_k)$ for basis vectors $e_k$ in $\Bbb R_n$.
>
> $|f(x)| \le \sum |\xi_k \gamma_k| \le (\sum_k \xi_k^2)^{1/2}(\sum_k \gamma_k^2)^{1/2} = \|x\| (\sum_k \gamma_k^2)^{1/2}$.
>
> Take the supremum over all $x$ of norm $1$ and we obtain
>
> $\|f\| \le (\sum_k \gamma_k^2)^{1/2}$.
>
> Since for $x = (\gamma_1, \dots, \gamma_n)$ we must have equality in Cauchy schwartz, we must have equality in the previous expression.

Can someone explain where these equalities are coming from?  I can't see how either of these show equality.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = (\gamma_1, \dots, \gamma_n)$ and $z:=\frac{x}{||x||}$. Then $||z||=1$ and

$|f(z)|=f(z)=\frac{1}{||x||}f(x)=\frac{1}{||x||}\sum_k \gamma_k^2=\frac{1}{||x||} \cdot ||x||^2=||x||=(\sum_k \gamma_k^2)^{1/2}.$

Thus we have a vector $z$ of norm $1$ such that $|f(z)|=(\sum_k \gamma_k^2)^{1/2}.$

Comment: Why is $|f(z)| = f(z)$?

Comment: We have  $f (z)=||x|| \ge 0$.

Comment: Where did you get that from?  I defined $f(x) = \sum_i \xi_i \gamma_i$.